# Tar overwrites read only files

Tags: permissions, files, tar, readonly

I created directory `test`, created file `1.txt` in `test`, wrote 'Before' in this file.
Then I went

```
cd ..
```

and used the command:

```
tar -cvzf ./test.tgz ./test
```

Then I entered the test dir again. Opened the `1.txt` file again. Changed content to "After". I saved the file and changed chmod to read only by executing:

```
chmod -w ./1.txt
```

So for now my `1.txt` is read only. Then I go up

```
cd ..
```

and extract the `test.tgz` archive.

```
tar -xvzf ./test.tgz
```

Then I go again to test dir, do

```
cat 1.txt
```

and get "Before".

It is not logical that this happens, since the file was set to be read-only.
Why does it happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tar didn't overwrite the existing read-only file, it removed it and then created a new file with the same name.  This is a consequence of the way -x works; it replaces existing versions of a file by design in order to accommodate the old incremental backup method of appending files to an existing archive.  A tar archive might have multiple versions of a file in it; only the last one will appear on disk after extraction is completed.  A side effect of this is that tar also removes existing copies of files even if they appear only once in the archive.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Kyle Jones.
So I will use --exclude option to exclude files I don't want to be overwritten.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that a file cannot be removed does not depend on a file's permissions being set to read-only, but on the permissions of the parent directory.

When you have **write access to a directory**, you can remove read-only files in that directory even if you do not own those files yourself ([link](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2006/10/finders-locum.html)).

```
# file removal test
(
mkdir -p test
echo hello > test/file.txt
chmod -w test
chmod -w test/file.txt
sudo chown root:wheel test/file.txt
#sudo chflags uchg test/file.txt
ls -ld test test/file.txt
rm -fv test/file.txt
echo
chmod 700 test  # set write permission
ls -ld test test/file.txt
rm -fv test/file.txt
)
```

If you remove the write access to the `test` directory in your example above, `gnutar` (on Mac OS X) cannot remove `test/1.txt` and complains:

```
# gnutar: ./test/1.txt: Cannot open: File exists
# gnutar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
# After

tartest() {
   dirperms="$1"
   mkdir -p test
   [[ -f test/1.txt ]] && chmod +w test/1.txt
   echo "Before" > test/1.txt
   gnutar -czf ./test.tgz ./test
   echo "After" > test/1.txt
   chmod -w test/1.txt
   chmod "${dirperms}" test
   gnutar -xzf ./test.tgz
   cat test/1.txt
   return 0
}

tartest 755
tartest 555
```